# Xamarin won't connect to my Macbook running OSX Sierra

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can ssh to macbook just fine but Xamarin cannot connect. It doesn't say the login is invalid it just says that it couldn't connect.

Comment: take a look at output, there must be an agent that is failing to start

Comment: It doesn't use an agent anymore these days. Just an ssh/remote connection. Any other ideas ?

Comment: maybe check the port it is trying to connect on and if that is in use?

Comment: Port is open as i can ssh through putty.

Comment: few other things to try listed here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55970/mac-agent-not-working-cant-connect hope these help :)

Comment: Yes that all works but that thread is back from in the time when xamarin still used a Mac Agent. These days it doesnt anymore. I have checked everything on the thread and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: There is a troubleshooting guide you should check out which also points to the logs that will likely hold clues as to what's going on there. Please make note of the known issues and workarounds: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Comment: Are you connecting via IP instead of name?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both ways.
Currently trying out what Alan Clark suggested.

Comment: Make sure xamarin on VS and on mac are the same (Check for updates on both and di installation if any).

Comment: They are, i tried reinstalling them both.

Comment: Neither of these things worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i finally got it working.
I changed the IP from Dynamic to Static and restarted the mac.
After it started back up i was able to connect without any problems !

Thanks for everyone that wanted to help me :)